# How to reduce Phosphor Icons CSS size 1.8MB at production?

Tags: css, angular, webpack, phosphor

We worked with a design agency that used the [phosphor icons](https://phosphoricons.com/).
The usage of the font is dead easy and the icons are great, but the CSS size is huge. *(In the past we used font awesome)*

We only use a dozen different icons but the css is 1.8MB at production build, which seems huge for the purpose.
I'd love to keep using the CSS as is out of the box but I am afraid of the size penalty.

**Background**
Angular-12 app with webpack build, CSS referenced in the styles

**Question**

What is the best practice to optimize such icon font for own prod purpose?

- Is 1.8MB just acceptable and we shouldn't worry?
- Could we create our own font with just the icons used?